# LogisticsEntityContactInfoView (table) has no valid runnable code in method 'entityType'

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012-r2

Error executing code: LogisticsEntityContactInfoView (table) has no valid runable code in method 'entityType'.

Stack trace

```
(S)\Data Dictionary\Views\LogisticsEntityContactInfoView\Methods\entityType
(S)\Classes\xApplication\dbSynchronize
(S)\Classes\Application\dbSynchronize - line 22
```

I encounter this error when I execute the synchronize database. 
How to solve this error?

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 0):

Have you fully [compiled your AX 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/dd309589.aspx) installation?

> If you installed a model other than the Foundation models, you must complete this task. If you do not complete this task, you will encounter errors when you run the Synchronize database task.

And remember....

> Depending on your hardware, compilation can take an hour or more. It is critical to let compilation run until it is complete.